# How can I monitor the new email events of all local mailbox folders in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, vsto

I developed a vsto plug-in. Every time I run Outlook, I need to add new mail events to all folders in the local mailbox. What I expect is that this event will be triggered when the mailbox folder is synchronized to new emails to obtain new email information.

```
_application = Application;

_nameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

_application.NewMailEx += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(ItemAdd);
```

I tried this code, but the NewMailEx event will only be triggered when a new email is received in the inbox folder.

```
private void ThisAddInStartup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
_dataFiles = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders;

var subFolders = _dataFiles.Cast<Outlook.Folder>()
                           .Where(dataFile => IsEmailFormat(dataFile.Name))
                           .SelectMany(dataFile => dataFile.Folders.Cast<Outlook.Folder>()).ToList();

subFolders.ForEach(async x =>
{
    await RecursionAsync(x);
});
}

 public async Task RecursionAsync(Outlook.Folder folder)
        {
            if (!IsExcludedFolder(folder.Name))
            {
                folder.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(ItemAdd);
                var restriction = $"[ReceivedTime] >= '{DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1):g}'";

                Outlook.Items filteredItems = folder.Items.Restrict(restriction);

                if (filteredItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Outlook.MailItem mailItem in filteredItems)
                    {
                        await _translateClient.OutlookTranslateTaskAsync(GetNeedToTranslatedContent(mailItem.HTMLBody), TranslationLanguage.ZhTw, mailItem.EntryID, _cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }

                if (folder?.Folders.Count > 0)
                    foreach (Outlook.Folder subFolder in folder.Folders) await RecursionAsync(subFolder);
            }
        }
```

I also tried this code but the ItemAdd event stopped this event from firing when using outlook

Comment: In addition, I just discovered that the itemaddd event was not triggered due to the custom task pane of the Inspector window. I commented out the custom task pane code and it was normal.

Comment: But I don't know what is causing this with the custom pane, can someone tell me? Greatful!

Answer (score 0):

The COM object firing events (`Items`) - must be kept alive to be able to fire events. The line `folder.Items.ItemAdd += ...` sets up an event handler on a temporary variable (`folder.Items`) that will be released when it goes out of scope and the Garbage Collector releases it. It must be kept alive to fire events. Create a wrapper class that takes `Folder` as a parameter and stores it and and its `Items` collection as class members (`_items = folder.Items;`). Set up the event handler on that member that points to a wrapper class method (`_items.ItemAdd += SomeHandler;`). Store the wrapper classes in a list to keep them alive.

That being said, setting event handlers on what can be hundreds or thousands of folders is a pretty bad idea. It is guaranteed to fail in online (no OST) mode. An event can be used as a hint that a sync must happen sooner rather than later, but it should not be used as a the sole trigger.

Comment: Write a timer to check all mail folders on this machine every five minutes to see if there are new mails within five minutes. Is it possible to judge this way?

Comment: As long as that check is efficient and does not loop through all items in a folder...